# new data in R statistic

Tags: r

such as applying a new data model, for example
a neural network and adjusting, as applied
to the new data, without having to train it again

I'm new at this and I could generate this, do
the models but I can not apply them to new data,
and the function apply, demands that the data to
be classified are of the same size as the training

Comment: Have you checked the G-diffuser?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're after, but you can use `predict` to apply your model on new data. E.g.

```
predict(your_model, newdata = your_new_data)
```